# Android anko alert not showing items

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm building AlertDialog using Anko library.

Everything is going fine with buttons, titles, etc. 
However when I'm trying to set list of items in alert body - they aren't showing (just blank: only title is showing)

Code:

```
alert("Pick address") {
                        items(listOf("one", "two")) { _, index ->
                            presenter.openNavigator(index)
                        }

                    }.show()
```

With regular AlertDialog things are working like charm:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this@PartnerView).setTitle("pick address")
                                .setItems(listOf("one", "two")) { _, item -> presenter.openNavigator(item) }
                                .create()
                                .show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a selector for this particular case (if there is a set of items to display), its more readable and more idiomatic.

```
selector("Pick adress", listOf("one", "two")) { _, _ ->}
```

This gives you an AlertDialog you require.

Comment: @Kubichko You are right. Your approach is better.
It doesn't solve the problem with Anko Alert, but is a good workaround.